# vs-code is using more than 2GB of RAM in ubuntu 18.04. Is there any solution to this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using visual studio code for more than 2 years now. I have been having problems lately and the computer is being not responding at all. And I have found that visual studio code is using more than 2GB of RAM. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You could try optimising some of the usage by following the steps mentioned here
https://dev.to/claudiodavi/reducing-vscode-memory-consumption-527k

Comment: the now removed `previewHTML` could use up to 2GB, the new `WebView` does not have this problem

Comment: Which version of VSCode?  What platform are you running it on?  What extensions do you have installed?  How are you measuring the memory usage?

Comment: I'm using 1.38 version of vscode in ubuntu 18.04 with gitlens extension and nothing more.

Comment: @yednap I know it's too late to answer, but also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658769/why-does-vs-code-require-so-much-memory-how-can-i-make-it-run-more-memory-effic)