Why does VSCode tunnel server take too much memory?
On Ubuntu 24.04 server (2GB RAM, 2vcpu, AWS), it hosts Visual Studio Code tunnel server to manage frontend (React) + backend (Django) projects. But sometimes the VM freezes when I started React project for testing with npm start. Freezing indicates dying of SSH-server, Apache2 server, VSCode tunnel server, and so forth (like OOM). After force reboots, started the tunnel and react so that reproduce problem.
As below, it's serious although VSC extensions installed are just 4;

Language pack
3 officials;

Python
Pylance
Python Debugger.



htop (VSC takes too large memory)
Is there a solution to reduce memory usage of VSC server?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658769/why-does-vs-code-require-so-much-memory-how-can-i-make-it-run-more-memory-effic (on Windows, but still might be some clues for solving there)
